# Filter the array with some criteria ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Hello guys I would like some code in ES6 javascript that solves this problem my data is an array of objects like the following

```js
array = [
{
  name: "SI",
  value: 3
},
{
  name: "MI",
  value: 2
},
{  
  name: "SI",
  value: 7
},
{ 
  name: "SI",
  value: 9
},
{
  name: "MI",
  value: 3
}
]
```

Just I want to take distinct object based on name with highest value like the following result

```
result = [
{ 
  name: "SI",
  value: 9
},
{
  name: "MI",
  value: 3
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate the distinct `name` in an object accumulator. For each stored object, compare the `value` with the stored `value` and update in case it is less than the current `value`

```js
let arr = [ { name:"SI", value:3 }, { name:"MI", value:2 }, { name:"SI", value:7 }, { name:"SI", value:9 }, { name:"MI", value:3 } ],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r,{name, value}) => {
      r[name] = r[name] || {name, value: 0};
      if(r[name].value < value)
        r[name].value = value;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: how can I change this code if the array object is structured like { creator{name:"MI",lastName:"MM"},value:3, comment:"hello value 3"} and I want to return creator and the value and comment and the createria still the max value and distinct creators with name

Comment: User `creator.name` instead of name and update the statement after OR condition.

Answer (score 0):

Probably most efficient by reducing to an intermediate object first, and then mapping that object's entries:

```
const result = Object.entries(array.reduce((a, {name, value}) => {
  a[name] = a[name] && a[name] >= value ? a[name] : value;
  return a;
}, {})).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));
```

Complete snippet:

```js
const array = [{
    name: "SI",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: "MI",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "SI",
    value: 7
  },
  {
    name: "SI",
    value: 9
  },
  {
    name: "MI",
    value: 3
  }
];

const result = Object.entries(array.reduce((a, {name, value}) => {
  a[name] = a[name] && a[name] >= value ? a[name] : value;
  return a;
}, {})).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));

console.log(result);
```